# How i go to the Specific URL.action in mvc 4 razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have dropdownlist which have two words like Load File and Send Mail, i want when i select Load File & press GO button its go own view & the same with Send Mail.
Here the below code I am using which is not working. In MVC 4 Razor View.

**JQuery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#go").click(function () {

        var tz = $("#Selector").val();
        var loader = "Email Loader";
        var Sender = "Send email";

        if (tz == loader) {
            document.location = '/Admin/Marketing/Load_File';
        }
        else if (tz == Sender)
        {
            document.location = '/Admin/Marketing/Send_Mail';
        }
    });

</script>
```

**and html code**

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm" id="Selector">
                        <option value="1">Email Loader</option>
                        <option value="2">Send email</option>

                    </select>

                </div>
     <div class="row">  
   <button class="btn red"style=" float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 32px;" id="go">Go</button> </div>
```

Comment: `$("#Selector").val();` returns either `1` or `2` (not `"Email Loader"` or `"Send email"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code with this

```
$("#go").click(function () {

    var tz = $("#Selector").val();
    var loader = "1";
    var Sender = "2";

  // your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to understand what actually going on...

`function go() {`
            `var Url;
            var location = document.getElementById("Selector").selectedIndex;
            if (location == 1) {
                Url = '/Admin/Marketing/Load_File';
            }
            else if (location == 2) {
                Url = '/Admin/Marketing/Send_Mail';
            }
            window.location.href=Url;
        }`

and write this in your button onclick event...

```
 onclick="Javascript:go();"
```